# exponential random variables of monitors

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> You have three computer monitors, and their lifetimes $T_{i}$ are exponential random variables with parameters$ \lambda_{i}=i,$ for i = 1,2,3 respectively. 
>   We switch on all monitors at time zero.

Find

(a) the mean time you have to wait until monitors three burns out

(b) the variance of the above time,

(c) P(at least one monitor is burnt out at time t)

(d) the mean time you have to wait until at least one of the monitors burns out

(e) the mean time you have to wait until all of the monitors burn out.

(f) P(exactly two monitors are burnt out at time t)

for part a I think it should be $\frac{1}{\lambda}$ which is 1/3

For part b it should by the definition

part c is 1-p(0) but I don't know what should I do next.

part e is it E(first)+E(second)+E(third)=1+0.5+1/3=11/6

part f is it since they are independent so var(three burns out)=var(1)+var(2)+var(3)

The else I got no idea to do

Answer (score 1):

- a) $\mathbb ET_3$
- b) $\text{Var}T_3$
- c) $\Pr(\min(T_1,T_2,T_3)<t)$
- d) $\mathbb E\min(T_1,T_2,T_3)$
- e) $\mathbb E\max(T_1,T_2,T_3)$
- f) $\Pr(T_1\leq t, T_2\leq t, T_3>t)+\Pr(T_1\leq t, T_2>t, T_3\leq t)+\Pr(T_1>t, T_2\leq t, T_3\leq t)$

For c) and d) it can be used that here also $\min(T_1,T_2,T_3)$ [has exponential distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution#Distribution_of_the_minimum_of_exponential_random_variables).

For f) make use of independency.

Comment: part c is  it equal to 1-exp(($\lambda1$+$\lambda2$+$\lambda3$)t)?

Comment: also i cant quite understand the f part